# Distribution check using R

Tags: r, distributions, likelihood

I want to check the probability distribution for my data using R.In some site I found `fitdistr` function in package `MASS` can do that. To check that I have generated 105 random Poisson numbers & run the `fitdistr` function to check whether it is able to identify or not. I used following code

```
library(MASS)
zpois=rpois(105,0.1)

fitdistr(zpois, 't')$loglik
fitdistr(zpois, 'normal')$loglik
fitdistr(zpois, 'logistic')$loglik
fitdistr(zpois, 'weibull')$loglik
fitdistr(zpois, 'gamma')$loglik
fitdistr(zpois, 'lognormal')$loglik
fitdistr(zpois, 'exponential')$loglik
fitdistr(zpois, 'Poisson')$loglik
fitdistr(zpois, 'negative binomial')$loglik
```

I found that it is giving lowest value for normal distribution. I know that the large sample approximation of Poisson distribution is normal distribution but I don't want the large sample approximation. I want to see the exact distribution.

Can you help me to guide the suitable function in R using which I can get the exact distribution fit?

Comment: You want the _highest_ log-likelihood, not the lowest.

Comment: Even if you had looked at the likelihood around the other way, you're asking for something that's not possible to do. You literally *cannot* be certain in a finite sample that your sample came from one distribution and not some other possible distribution. As the sample size becomes large, you will be able to rule out more and more distributions as possibilities, but there will always be an infinite number of distributions closer to the sample than the Poisson distribution, no matter how large your sample -- *even if you generated it from a Poisson*. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) You may eventually rule out all commonly used distributions other than generalizations of the Poisson, but when you have data that's not generated by an algorithm (as with your test), you can't know that the data comes from one of those commonly used ones. Indeed, in most cases you can be quite sure it *doesn't*.

Comment: Actually my main goal is to check if the data follows poisson distribution or not. Is there any way to check that using R?

Comment: To repeat myself: You can perhaps *rule out* some possibilities. Nothing will *ever* tell you 'this came from a Poisson distribution'. In some situations, you may be able to say 'this sample is highly inconsistent with a Poisson distribution'. But you *won't* be able to say 'this is Poisson'. The best you can hope for along those lines is 'this sample isn't really inconsistent with a Poisson' -- but it may be (in fact, it will be) even more consistent with an infinite number of other possibilities. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) Goodness of fit tests exist, which if they reject the null indicate that the sample isn't really consistent with a Poisson (though true Poisson data will once in a while do the same - in fact you choose how often that happens). Or you can use diagnostic displays which will show how close to consistent with a Poisson your data appear to be. A crucial question: why are you trying to do this?

Comment: +1 to @Glen_b 's last sentence. This is always a crucial question and is often not stated.

Comment: To add to the other comments, the likelihood values reported by R for these different distributions are not directly comparable, because R leaves out certain constants which are deemed "unnecessary" because they are constant within the family. That leaves out the possibility of comparing fits from different families!

Answer (score 0):

Much useful information in the comments here, but I must add a point overseen by the commenters: You are trying to compare the fits by looking at their log-likelihood values. In R this is simply invalid, because R is often leaving out from the computation certain constants deemed unnecessary, because they are constant within the distribution family! But that simply **invalidates** comparing different distribution families this way. So you need to look for other methods ...

Comment: As far as I can see, this is not documented. If you know that this is so (personally I haven't checked, so I don't), I think you should tell the package maintainer to add this information to the help page accordingly. Users can legitimately assume that the loglik component has the log-likelihood if the help page tells them so.

Comment: @ChristianHennig:  This might not be documented, but it is well known. [Look at this old R-help post by R-core member T Lumley](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-February/088735.html), his second note!  [Also this follow-up by B Ripley](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-February/088745.html)

Comment: But Lumley's comment refers to "different R functions" whereas the question uses Ripley's fitdistr function for all fits. Its loglik component is documented as "the log-likelihood", and if it isn't the plain log-likelihood in all cases, this should be documented for sure, regardless of whether Lumley, Ripley, or some other experts know this already. (I'm actually not sure whether your claim refers to the fitdistr function or whether you are rather saying that there are some R functions doing things differently even though not mentioned in the question.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig: I will look concretely into the fitdistr function later today. But note that fitdistr is written originally, at least, by B Ripley who has written that AIC should onlky be use to compare nested models. In that case it is OK to leave out constants ...

Comment: Even if no constants are dropped in the implementation: Can the log-likelighood value actually be considered a measure for goodness of fit of a parametric family? At least, ML estimation (unlike least squares) does not maximize the good-ness-of fit, as this small simulation demonstrates: https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/10069